# Clickable intra-document cross reference across table of contents, chapters, figures and references

Tags: cross-referencing

I am among the batch of students who now require to submit their PhD thesis entirely online instead of paper. While that is good (for the trees), it makes document navigation a bit harder. This is a concern as I feel my external examiner may not be very tech savvy and may be used to turning pages.
Is it possible to make a Table of contents where, if I click Chapter 3, subsection 4, I go to that place? Likewise, if I click on the chapter header, I want it to come back to the table of contents (it really helps with navigation).
Similarly, I would to click on list of Figure, say, figure no. 4 and go to that spot and vice versa. Oh and the same with references as well?

Comment: Search for hyperref package.

Comment: Thanks. Will look into this :)